# Laravel passport generate user access and refresh token with only user id

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Currently i would like to generate user access and refresh token after registering a user inorder to automatically login a user after registrations

Currently am doing this.

```
     $user = User::create(//user detaisl) //this creates a user


     $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => env("APP_URL"),
        'defaults' => [
            'exceptions' => false
        ]
    ]);
    $response = $guzzle->post('/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => env("PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID"),
            'client_secret' => env("PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET"),
            'username' => $user->email,
            'password' => $request->input("password"),
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

The above with guzzle works but i was wondering if there is a simpler way to simply generate access and refresh tokens without need to perform another guzzle http request by simply using the user id after create.
I would like this as guzzle sometimes fails to work especially on localhost during development continously hangs.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a guzzle request, you can call directly the controller method that handles the token route. Generally directly calling another controller method is a bit of a code smell. You could attempt to dive into the code to refactor this out if you wanted, but since you don't "own" the passport code, I wouldn't worry about it.

```
// Save off the original request object.
$originalRequest = app('request');

// Create a new request object for the token request.
$tokenRequest = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create('/oauth/token', 'POST', [
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => config('passport.password_client_id'),
    'client_secret' => config('passport.password_client_secret'),
    'username' => $user->email,
    'password' => $request->input("password"),
]);

// Replace the current request with the new token request in the app container.
app()->instance('request', $tokenRequest);

// Call the access token controller method using the app container,
// which will auto inject the new request.
$response = app()->call('\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken');

// Replace the token request in the container with the original request.
app()->instance('request', $originalRequest);

return $response;
```

A couple notes:

- The `$user->createToken()` method creates personal access tokens, not password grant tokens. Personal access tokens cannot be refreshed.
- I converted the `env()` calls to `config()` calls. You should avoid using the `env()` method outside of the config files. As soon as you cache your config, the `env()` calls will return null (for values only set in the `.env` file).